# Scala class method with WSClient call inside an object in play framework

Tags: scala, class, methods, playframework, ws

I am new to scala and play.So how can i call a method defined inside the class with WSClient from an object

```
import play.api.libs.ws._
class Application @Inject() (ws: WSClient){
def myMethod()={}
}

object Abc{
//need to call "myMethod" here
}
```

Could anyone please provide some insight on this.

Comment: Could you add details on why you need to call it from inside an `object`? In general, dependency injection is not easily compatible with the use of singleton objects in Scala.

Answer (score 2):

create an instance of the class (Application) and you can call **myMethod** using that.

```
import play.api.libs.ws._
class Application @Inject() (ws: WSClient){
def myMethod()={}
}

object Abc{
//need to call "myMethod" here
implicit val system = ActorSystem()
implicit val materializer = SystemMaterializer(system).materializer

 val wsClient = StandaloneAhcWSClient()
 val application = new Application()(wsClient)
  application.myMethod();
}
```

For detailed example refer to this [Play WS standalone](https://github.com/playframework/play-ws#scala-1)

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer.Is there any difference in using this approach?like performance wise or in anyway?

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve. If you can elaborate more on the requirements part then I can suggest. In general, it is preferable using the DI unless you're using this as a scripting purpose.

Comment: Using for get data from external URL.But the issue is i need to call it from one object which is already existing.

Comment: Do you mean calling from ABC? the existing one is Application? or vice versa.
Is this play rest API service?

Comment: Existing one is Abc.. yes this is play rest api

Comment: yes.then you can use the above logic, the key is here to pass the WSClient either directly or through implicitly.